# ImageAdapter returning NullPointerException from HashMap put method

Tags: java, android

I am getting a NullPointerException when try to add String value to a HashMap in Adapter class:

```
HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
....
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ....
    //---Returns the number of images---
    public int getCount() {
        return getCursor.getCount();
    }
    ....
    //---Returns the ImageView view---
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null)   
           imageView = new ImageView(context);
        else 
           imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        getCursor.moveToPosition(position);
        int imageID       = getCursor.getInt(columnIndex);    //--- Returns unique ID --
        String fileName   = getCursor.getString(arrayIndex);  //--- Returns  filepath --
        String imageValue = String.valueOf(imageID);
        try {
            map.put(imageValue, fileName);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "Line154: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        Log.d("DEBUG", imageValue + " " + fileName);
```

I do not understand this as the final line above shows the correct string values, so why the error? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Is the variable 'map' being initialised? I can't see where it is being set or defined and a NullReference would lead to me suspect the map you are trying to add to is null.

Answer (score 0):

Where is

```
 HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Is this (below) a nested class you are showing us?

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {
```

If it is a nested class please show us the parent class. If not place

```
 HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

within the ImageAdapter class

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized the 'HashMap' outside the class. Try initializing it inside the class 'ImageAdapter'.

Comment: OK I have added the HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>() inside the class, which works, but now I am getting a "new" map each iteration with only 1 entry; Log.d("DEBUG", imageValue + " " + fileName + " " + map.size()) showing 1 each time.

Answer (score 0):

`Log.d("DEBUG", imageValue + " " + fileName);`
Your final line is showing the right value because imageValue and fileName are both member variables of ImageAdapter class.

However, `HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();`
is not defined within the class and hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you show the complete code and logcat. Anyway there has a proplem in your code:

`ImageView imageView;
 if (convertView == null)

    imageView = new ImageView(context);
 else 
    imageView = (ImageView) convertView;`

it will never run in else block.

Answer (score 0):

I can now answer this myself - after a lot of extra research. What is needed is a HashMap with
Global scope (that was why I originally declared it outside the class). The way to do this 
is by extending the Application class as in the code below, after changing
the XML manifest to allow this(see Google development):

```
try {
    CustomHashMap thisMap = (CustomHashMap)getApplicationContext();
    thisMap.addKeyValue(imageValue,fileName);

    Log.d("DEBUG", "Line140 " + String.valueOf(thisMap.getSize()));
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    Log.d("DEBUG", "Line154: " + e.toString());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
....
public static class CustomHashMap extends Application {
    HashMap<String, String> myMap;

    public CustomHashMap() {
        super();
        this.myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }

    public HashMap getMap() {
        return myMap;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return myMap.size();
    }

    public void addKeyValue(String x, String y) {
        myMap.put(x,y);
    }
}
```

The LogCat line now correctly indicates the increasing size of the single HashMap on every iteration.